# Find $y \in W_{2}^{1}[-1,1]$ s.t. $\forall x \in W_{2}^{1}[-1,1]$, $f(x)=\langle x, y \rangle$

Tags: functional-analysis, analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, sobolev-spaces, inner-products

Consider a Sobolev space $W_{2}^{1}[-1,1]$ with the following inner product:

$\langle x, y \rangle = \int_{-1}^{1} [x(t)y(t)+x^{\prime}(t)y^{\prime}(t)]dt$.

Let $f(x) = \int_{-1}^{1}e^{2t}x(t)dt$.

I need to find $y \in$ the Sobolev space $W_{2}^{1}[-1,1]$ such that $\forall x \in W_{2}^{1}[-1,1]$, $f(x)=\langle x, y \rangle$.

However, I don't even know how to begin. I know that I need $\int_{-1}^{1} [x(t)y(t)+x^{\prime}(t)y^{\prime}(t)]dt = \int_{-1}^{1}e^{2t}x(t)dt$, but that's about where what looks familiar to me ends...

I've since been informed that what I need to do is find a weak solution of $-y^{\prime\prime} + y = e^{2t}$; however, I have no idea how one goes from the problem I have here to this, much simpler-looking, ODE. **A detailed explanation as to where this comes from is needed.**

**Also, I don't know what boundary conditions I'm supposed to use.** I am not doing this for a Differential Equations course; I am doing it in a Functional Analysis course, where my exposure to differential equations in the past has been extremely limited (as in, haven't had a class in ODEs since 2003, and even then, it was very basic). **Please explain this to me.** Then, after I have my solution to the homogeneous form of the 2nd order linear ODE, I should be able to figure out the particular solution (I hope) using either variation of parameters or undetermined coefficients.

Comment: You are looking for a weak solution of the equation $-y''+y=e^{2t}$. You should try to understand what boundary conditions are naturally associated to this definition of weak solution.

Comment: @Siminore, I've never seen weak solutions with ODEs before, only PDEs. Or is this the method of undetermined coefficients?

Comment: ODEs are easier to solve than PDEs. Just solve it, and then check if your solution belongs to the correct Sobolev space and if it satisfies the orthogonality condition.

Comment: @Siminore, okay, I'm still working on this one. I don't have a lot of experience with solving ODEs. First of all, how exactly did you show that $\int_{-1}^{1}[x(t)y(t)+x^{\prime}(t)y^{\prime}(t)]dt = \int_{-1}^{1}e^{2t}x(t)dt$ reduces to $-y^{\prime\prime} + y = e^{2t}$? I know that the latter is a second-degree linear non-homogeneous ODE with constant coefficients. But I don't understand how you got from one thing to the other. Can you please explain it to me in more detail? Thank you.

Comment: @arctictern, don't forget about me ;)

Comment: try integration by parts on the term $x'y'$. also assume $y'$ is zero at the end points

Comment: @Joel, what about the $xy$-term?

Comment: @JessyCat, you leave that term alone. The method of arctic tern's answer is exactly what I had in mind. We look for a weak solution in that we are requiring $y$ to have two derivatives instead of just one. This is a stronger requirement than is imposed by membership in the Sobolev space.

Comment: @Joel, thanks. I'm good now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Okay, so let's write out the condition $f(x)=\langle x,y\rangle$...

$$\int_{-1}^1 x(t)y(t)+x'(t)y'(t)\,\mathrm{d}t=\int_{-1}^1 e^{2t}x(t)\,\mathrm{d}t.$$

Observe we may write

$$\begin{array}{ll} \displaystyle \int_{-1}^1 x'(t)y'(t)\,\mathrm{d}t & \displaystyle =\int_{-1}^1 \left[\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}t}\big( x(t)y'(t)\big)-x(t)y''(t)\right]\mathrm{d}{t} \\ & \displaystyle =x(1)y'(1)-x(-1)y'(-1)-\int_{-1}^1 x(t)y''(t)\,\mathrm{d}t \end{array}$$

To get rid of the terms outside of the integral impose boundary conditions $y'(1)=y'(-1)=0$.

Then the original equation may be rewritten as

$$ \int_{-1}^1 \left[\color{Blue}{y(t)-y''(t)}\right]x(t)\,\mathrm{d}t=\int_{-1}^1 \color{Blue}{e^{2t}}\,x(t)\,\mathrm{d}t. $$

The only way this can be true for all functions $x(t)$ is if

$$-y''+y=e^{2t}. $$

With the ansatz $y=\alpha e^{2t}$ we find $y=-\frac{1}{3}e^{2t}$ is a particular solution, however this doesn't satisfy the correct boundary conditions. The homogeneous solutions are $e^t$ and $e^{-t}$, so we may write out the form $y=\alpha e^t+\beta e^{-t}-\frac{1}{3}e^{2t}$, in which case the boundary conditions you should be able to write out as linear equations to solve for in $\alpha$ and $\beta$.

Comment: I'm going to comb through this, but it makes a lot of sense to me. Differential equations are not something I'm that comfortable with, but this is extremely comprehensible!

Comment: I'm actually having a little bit of trouble solving for $\alpha$ and $\beta$, which I'm calling $c_{1}$ and $c_{2}$ here. Are they supposed to be extremely ugly expressions in terms of different powers of $e$? Specifically, I got $\displaystyle c_{1}=\frac{2e}{3(1+e^{2})}$ and $\displaystyle c_{2}=\frac{2(1+e^{2}+e^{4})}{3(e+e^{3})}$, which are just hideous.

Comment: @JessyCat If you were able to fit them in a comment then they can't be that hideous. In any case the values I get are different: $\displaystyle \alpha=\frac{1}{3}\frac{\cosh3}{\cosh2}$ and $\displaystyle \beta=-\frac{1}{3}\frac{\sinh 1}{\sinh 2}$.